# Jquery JSON call: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: jquery, ajax, steam, steam-web-api

I want my site to be able to retrieve steam item prices like below:

http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=Operation%20Phoenix%20Weapon%20Case

Right now i have this code:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "Get",
    url : "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview",
    data :"currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=" + steaminfo_inventory[3][index][7],
    dataType :"jsonp",
    jsonp: false,
    success : function(data){
        alert(data);},
});
```

I keep getting an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`. It seems like i am still receiving the data, but i still get the error. When i click on the error in chrome i am seeing this output: `{"success":true,"lowest_price":"0,06&#8364;","volume":"107,179","median_price":"0,06&#8364; "}`

Any help is appreciated Thanks.

Comment: From which line you get that error?

Comment: The error does not give me a line number

Comment: The `,` at the end after your alert looks suspicious.

Comment: @ThomasVestergaard, set your devtools to pause on exceptions to see what's happening. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Answer (score 0):

If you use JSONP, must set callback function in response.
jQuery added automatically callback into get params.

Try change response on backend to GETcallback;

Example:
Url -> http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=Operation%20Phoenix%20Weapon%20Case&callback=testCallback

Response -> `testCallback({"success":true,"lowest_price":"0,06&#8364;","volume":"107,179","median_price":"0,06&#8364; "});`